# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found in VS code Jupyter notebook with anaconda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, visual-studio-code

I have anaconda installed and I have changed the interpreter on the top right to my anaconda environment.
When imported a library I am getting the following error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

I have added the following variables in `PATH`

```
C:\Users\name\anaconda3
C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Library
C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\name\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
```

I have added the following variables in Preferences:Settings(JSON)

```
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "C:\\Users\\name\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\Users\\name\\anaconda3"],
    "python.condaPath": "C:\\Users\\name\\anaconda3\\conda.exe"
```

None of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer if anyone is stuck on the same issue. After trying the two above-mentioned steps. I have opened the terminal in VS code and activated my environment

```
conda activate myenv
```

Next run

```
>code .
```

in the VS code's terminal. If it does not work close VS code and repeat this step.

If the issue still persists then

1. Open anaconda prompt.
2. Change the directory to location where jupyter notebook is preset.
3. execute `code .`
4. Try running the import statement now.

[Source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15183#issuecomment-627946494)